# i want to update whole json in json data type column

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a column in postgresql database in json data type. I want to update the whole json in a row. Please suggest how can I do that. I tried to do with update sql function but it did not work.

```
UPDATE "WORKER_DATA" 
   SET raw_data = '{"dbInfo":{"id":"8","lifeTime":"DELETED"}}' 
WHERE id = '8';
```

and I want to update whole json so how i do that i have a this json in my db

```
{"dbInfo":{"id":"8","lifeTime":"ACTIVE","version":"3"}}
```

i want to update whole json

```
{"dbInfo":{"id":"8","lifeTime":"OFFLINE","version":"52"}}
```

Comment: The update should work just fine. What is the problem you have?

Comment: i dont know but its not reflecting in db

Comment: do you issue `commit` at the end?

Comment: yes i use commit at end

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
WHERE raw_data -> 'dbInfo' ->> 'id' = "8" AND raw_data -> 'dbInfo' ->> 'lifeTime' = "DELETED";
```

and will update all tuples (rows) with dbInfo.id = 8 and dbinfo.lifeTime = DELETED

Whole instruction:

```
UPDATE WORKER_DATA 
 SET raw_data = '{"dbInfo":{"id":"8","lifeTime":"OFFLINE","version":"52"}}' 
WHERE 
raw_data -> 'dbInfo' ->> 'id' = "8" 
 AND raw_data -> 'dbInfo' ->> 'lifeTime' = "DELETED";
```

In this fiddle, you can see the example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a21d9b/11

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a21d9/8 check this i want to do this and its not working